# Take a known number of inputs

Tags: rust

I am looking to take a known number of inputs in rust. In this case I'm taking in poker hands for problem 54 of project Euler where each line parses into a two hands of five cards each. There are two main approaches I've found to this situation neither of which I like.

Approach 1:

```rust
let mut buffer_1 = Vec::with_capacity(5);
for i in 0..5 {
    buffer_1.push(i)
}
assert_eq!(buffer_1.len(), 5);
```

Approach 2:

```rust
let mut buffer_2 = [None, 5];
for i in 0..5 {
    buffer_2[i as usize] = Some(i)
}
```

Approach 1 is on the heap despite having a known size at compile time and approach 2 gives me a optional values where I know everything is a `Some`. What I would ideally like is something capable of collecting some function or colsure into an array or similar. e.g.

```rust
fn array_from_colsure<T>(length: usize, closure: fn() -> T) -> Option<[T; length]> {
    // implementation
}
#[test]
fn array_from_closure_test() {
    let a: [i32; 5] = array_from_colsure(5, || {for i in 0..5 {i}}).unwrap()
}
```

**Clarification:**
I am looking to find something with this functionality not create it from scratch.

As Silvio Mayolo's excellent answer shows (I have edited the desired functionality slightly since the original question), implementing my suggestion will require a horrific amount of `unsafe` code (not to mention an awful lot of effort for such a small optimisation). So it is not sensible to do it for a small number of projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::array::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/fn.from_fn.html):

```
let buffer: [i32; 5] = std::array::from_fn(|i| i as i32);
```

---

I also offer up `ArrayVec` from either the [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) or [tinyvec](https://crates.io/crates/tinyvec) crates which would look like your first approach but wouldn't use a heap allocation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Those crates look extremely useful too, I've been looking for something like those for a while.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me just say that what you're doing here is *prematurely optimizing*. You're trying to save microseconds at the expense of writing readable, maintainable code. Approach 1 has the correct type, never reallocates, and is immediately obvious to a human reader, so you should absolutely use Approach 1.

*However,* let's pretend we're on a microprocessor. We're running on some embedded machine in a hospital, every single byte counts, and heap allocations are problematic. [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) can be used to allocate stack space without storing anything in it.

```
let mut buffer: [MaybeUninit<i32>; 5] = unsafe {
  MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()
};
```

That's a pretty confusing statement. We're creating some uninitialized memory, and then asserting that it's initialized. But it's not: it's uninitialized. Well, what `assume_init` is *really* saying is "this memory is as initialized as is required for the type", and since the array only contains `MaybeUninit`, it's fine for that type to be uninitialized.

```
for (i, elem) in buffer.iter_mut().enumerate() {
  elem.write(i as i32);
}
```

Now we write some data. I'm assuming your actual calculation is more sophisticated than `i as i32`, but for this example it'll do fine.

```
let buffer = unsafe { transmute::<_, [i32; 5]>(buffer) };
println!("{:?}", buffer);
```

Now we've got an array of maybe-uninitialized values that we know are initialized. Since `MaybeUninit<T>` and `T` have the same memory representation, we can transmute one into the other. [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) has no runtime overhead, because it's literally just reinterpreting the bytes of one type into the bytes of another. Here's our whole block of code.

```
let mut buffer: [MaybeUninit<i32>; 5] = unsafe {
  MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()
};
for (i, elem) in buffer.iter_mut().enumerate() {
  elem.write(i as i32);
}
let buffer = unsafe { transmute::<_, [i32; 5]>(buffer) };
println!("{:?}", buffer);
```

The amount of `unsafe` here should scare you. It should make you run and call the Rust police. There's a reason we don't write code this way normally. But it *can* be done, if you ever find yourself in that one-in-a-million situation where the extra handful of bytes are really worth this much complexity.

Comment: Thanks. However, you have slightly misunderstood what I am looking for, as your explanation shows, this kind of functionality requires a horrific amount of `unsafe` code so I'm not looking to implement this myself. However, this strikes me as the type of thing that either the standard library or some crate may have functionality for. Therefore, I am looking for something that can do this for me not how to do it myself.

Comment: For an integer, or any type with a cheap default, going to `unsafe` is just not worth it. Just use a dummy value and overwrite it. Really.